# UML class diagram design

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am trying to implement the UML class diagram for the first time. This is the [class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMIbt.png)  which I have been work through: 
[image]

This is the requirement:
[image]

I do not expect anyone do it for me, but I think I need someone help to check where I can improve or I anything is missing. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [class diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html) is a structural diagram.  Behaviors (e.g. adding, deleteing, etc...) shall not appear therein, except if you decide to make them operations of one class.

Here how to understand the requirements:

- R1. Classes `GroceryList`, `Item` and `User`.  Association between 0..n `GroceryList` and 0..n `Item`.  Association class with property `Quantity`
- R2. Class `ItemType`
- R3. Association between 0..n `Item` and 1 `ItemType`. Both classes have a property `Name`
- R6. Association class also has property `CheckOff`
- R10. Association between 1 `User` and 0..n `GroceryList`.  `GroceryList` has a property `Name`
- Assumption:  `User` has a property `Name`

If your teacher never told you what an association class is, then use a class `ListItem` instead, with an association of 0..n `ListItems` with 1 `Item`, and a coposition link from `GroceryList` to `ListItem`

Remove any other box in your diagram, because these are either behaviors, or a duplicate of an existing class.

For the operations, it is not clear to me because it depends on the architecture of your application (e.g. will you use repository classes?).

Comment: what do you mean Association class? do you mean the line between two class?

Comment: it is a class that describes the association: more [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCLKU_7.5.5/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cassnclss.html)